# How to join integers with a comma without haveing a trailing comma at the end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If I do this:

```
users.each do |u|
   str += u.id.to_s + ','
end
```

I will end up with:

```
1,3,234,234,
```

Is there a style of looping that won't leave the trailing `','` at the end? I know I can `chomp` it off after the loop, but was looking for a way to do it w/o having to do that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Or even shorter:

```
users.map(&:id).join ','
```

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out but wasted time looking up #join before typing. Good catch.

Comment: @DanneManne Not true at all. There is a practical line between code 'simplicity' and 'readability' that all too often gets tipped in the direction of the former. Not saying you have crossed it with this particular solution, but in regard to your generalized comment I would have to strongly disagree. Given your answer has in fact helped me, I have appropriately upvoted it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
users.map { |u| u.id.to_s }.join ','
```

And actually, `#join` will do the `#to_s` for you, so on second thought:

```
users.map(&:id).join ','
```

Comment: can you explain a little what map is doing?  &:id is a block?

Comment: @Blankman: Look up the documentation for `Symbol#to_proc`. Basically what it does is equivalent to `{ |u| u.id }`.

Comment: Right, Ruby should have a FAQ for easily-missed API doc locations. `&` is always about turning a block into a proc, or, as in this case, a proc into a block. The `&` operation will try to convert any non-proc argument into a proc with #to_proc. As it happens, if you look up `class Symbol` in the core API docs, you will find `#to_proc`, it's shorthand for a block with a single method call.